# This is the man who was chasing me last night. This is the man that was chasing me last night

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

What's the difference between these two sentences? 
Can we use ***that*** as a relative pronouns in this sentence? 
As I know read in books that ***who*** is better than *that* but I am not sure how to use ***that*** to connect two sentences together?

> This is the man **who** was chasing me last night.
>   This is the man **that** was chasing me last night.

Comment: @CopperKettle Yes, but we also use *that* :-)

Comment: I think there is no issue in using "that" ! With persons we also use whose and whom! :D

Comment: But "that"can also be used indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Both work, but *that* is informal.

When the relative clause is a defining one (the present case), you can use both. However if you have a **non-defining relative** clause, you can't use *that*. For instance,

> This is the man, a robber, **who** was chasing me.
>   <s>This is the man, a robber, **that** was chasing me.</s>

Comment: Hmm ... your principle is right, but your second example may be acceptable: putting the appositive *a robber* in there makes it is ambiguous whether a restrictive (defining) or non-restrictive (non-defining) clause is to be understood.